# Compressing an array of two values

Tags: compression

What is the cheapest way to compress an array, to a byte[] array, given only two possible values in it?
Array length has no limit.
The best idea I have seen so far is to insert the repeated number of times each value appears, so for example the array  "11111001" is compressed to "521".
I wonder if there is a better way.
Thanks.

Comment: The compression technique is likely to be dependant on the data and the language which you are using. Run Length Encoding which you are describing is efficient, only if there are sizeable repeated values.

Answer (score 0):

First off, convert to a bit array. Right off the bat it will take 1/8th the space.

Then you'd need to examine your data to see if there is any apparent redundancy. If not, you're done. If there is redundancy, you'd need to figure out a way to model it, and then compress it. Run-length coding as you propose is useful only if long runs of zeros and/or ones are common in the data.

Comment: So, there is not absolute best way to compress this array, but assuming long runes of zeros and ones, Run length coding is probably the best?

Comment: Whether it can be compressed at all depends on the data. Run length coding may or may not help, depending on the data. No, there is no "best" way to compress without knowing more about the data than that it is a string of bits. _All_ data is a string of bits.